# How to light the whole scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor, light

A directional light illuminates only a part, but I need the light to be “everywhere”. I do not want any shading anywhere, as in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTpGi.jpg)

Comment: So use an area light and turn off shadows?

Comment: It helps me but it's now what I want

Comment: We all the screen shot you provided has shadows, its hard to know what exactly you are looking for

Comment: No, it doesn't using shadows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ambient Light, and set it from the [Lighting Window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GlobalIllumination.html)

Otherwise consider that you might also set an Area Light - see more in [Types of Light](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lighting.html) - Unity Manual.